# In Refinery CMS, how can I change the template for the pages generated by the Inquiries extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I tried the simple approach: editing the Contact page in the admin interface and selecting my new template within the Advanced Options section. But the form does not get displayed.

I also generated the override views:

```
 rake refinery:override view=refinery/inquiries/inquiries/*
```

But looking at the `app\views\refinery\inquiries\inquiries\new.html.erb` file, I did not see an obvious solution to this issue.

I found this issue on github but it does not offer much detail: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-inquiries/issues/45

I suspect a big part of the issue is that when I change the template setting under Advanced Options, it's changing the view from the default inquiries new.html.erb to one of the standard view options. The problem is inquires extension `new` view is not listed as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is: you can't.

In the course of struggling with this, I came to realize that in most cases you probably don't want to be switching layouts. Not in the casual manner that I was, anyway.

What I really wanted were alternate page *views*. The basic web page layout and styling can be fully modified through views.

Realizing this changed my objective. I didn't need to change the layout for the inquiry pages. I needed to match the inquiry page views to my default page view. I was able to do this by overriding the inquiries extension's `new` and `thank-you` views and editing those files so that the markup and styling matched that of my default page view.

Simple enough. The only downside is it's a bit un-DRY. If I were to alter my page view, I now would likely have to repeat the changes in those two views as well.